# regex to extract data from wikimedia formatted markup documents

Tags: regex, clojure, wikipedia

i'm trying to extract some data from the wikipedia/wikimedia markup structure in clojure.

```
{{Infobox company
...
...
|operating_income = {{Increase}} US$ 26.76&amp;nbsp;billion (2013)&lt;ref name=10K/&gt;
|net_income       = {{Increase}} US$ 21.86&amp;nbsp;billion (2013)&lt;ref name=10K/&gt;
|assets           = {{Increase}} US$ 142.43&amp;nbsp;billion (2013)&lt;ref name=10K/&gt;
|equity           = {{Increase}} US$ 78.94&amp;nbsp;billion (2013)&lt;ref name=10K/&gt;
...
}}
```

i need the information within the `{{infobox company .... }}` area.

so i used this regex `(re-seq #"\{\{(.*?)}\}" above-txt)`

but that gave me some of the regexes but still not all. there is a lot of extra data on this page as well as nested {{ }}

you can see the full text at http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=microsoft&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

i think the problem with my regex is that its not dealing with nested {{ .. }} tags.

Comment: How deep nesting can you expect? If unlimited, then you are basically out of luck with regular expressions. (Well, Perl "regular expressions" support recursive patterns - do you know if clojure supports them too?)

Comment: @volferine: Clojure uses Java's regex engine which does support some non-regular stuff like back references, but not Perl's recursive patterns like `(?PARNO)`.

Comment: There are only 2 nesting levels. the top one {{Infobox... and inside that area, smaller  ones.. i'm especially interested in content on each side of the `=`

Answer (score 0):

If regular expressions get frustrating you could consider using [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) to make a small parser that could handle arbitrarily nested expressions. I's a bit heavier weight though it will work on more input types.